# Attribute required = false in special cases

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a User model with a lot of attributes and validation rules:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = 'Serviceorder';

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A name is required'
            )
        ),
        ...
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        ),
        ...
    );
}
```

This makes sense to me because when creating a user a password is always required.
In some cases, like when editing a user, I don't want the password to be required. When there's no new password, the password is not changed. How can I do that?

Comment: [see this article](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/) for some ideas on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the password validation as below :-

```
   'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A password is required',
            'on' => 'create'
        )
    ),
```

Comment: Generally working, but it seems as my password is changed although I leave it empty. Any way to prevent this?

Comment: print your post data and find that is there any field for password? if yes then unset it first, it may post blank password every time you are updating

Comment: There is a field, yes. Because I want to give the possibility to change the password. But if it's empty, then the password stays the same. Unset didn't help ... Strange.